# Is there a way to submit a form without refreshing the page using only PHP and JavaScript?

Tags: php

I have a project at college and I don't want to refresh the page after submitting a form.

The problem is that for this project I'm only allowed to use the base programming languages, therefore I can't use jQuery (I found a solution for this using the post method) or any kind of library or framework. Is there any other way to do it?

If there is no way to do it without additional libraries/frameworks, what would be the best way to get the form information using PHP? Should the form have the GET or POST method? I've seen many different types online and I want to be sure which one would work best (Login, Register forms for example which I do have on my project).

Comment: jQuery is just a wrapper around plain Javascript, making it easier to use. So yes, you can do it using just plain javascript, it just takes a bit more work to dive into using a raw XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: this might be helpful for you - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_send.asp

Comment: MDN has a [reasonable example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript#Using_FormData_bound_to_a_form_element) of how to submit a form using XHR and `FormData`

Comment: In general, use GET for read operations, and POST for write operations. Register would be a POST, and login is probably a GET, unless there is something that happens remotely that you don't want to have repeated (e.g. send the user an email if there is suspicious login activity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pure JS and PHP, here is a simple example of it. You can use events listeners and *XMLHttpRequest* object to make the request. I recomend use POST request.

### Whats the difference between POST and GET?

Both GET and POST method is used to transfer data from client to server in HTTP protocol, but the major difference between both methods is that GET carries request parameter appended in URL string while POST carries request parameter in message body, which makes it more secure way of transferring data from client to server in http protocol. Usually when you are handling data such as **pass** and **email** you must use POST, to avoid security problems

```js
var myForm = document.getElementById('my_form');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // To avoid the page refresh when you click on submit button
})

function login() {
  let userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value
  let userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value
  console.log(`Email: ${userEmail} - Pass: ${userPass}`); // Will print your data
  
  let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let url = 'get_data.php'; // Your PHP controller
  let params = `email=${userEmail}&pass=${userPass}`;
  http.open('POST', url, true);

  // Send the proper header information along with the request
  http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  http.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
      if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
          alert(http.responseText);
      } else {
          console.log('Unable to make the request');
      }
  }
  http.send(params);
}
```

```html
 <form id="my_form">
    <div>
      <input type="email" id="email_field" placeholder="email">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="password" id="password_field" placeholder="password">
    </div>
    <button onclick="login()">login</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)? since you can't use frameworks or libraries, just use the javascript's XMLHttpRequest object. Don't forget to make a PHP script to handle that request.

For the HTTP method choice, you can refer to [this](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/) documentation if you want to conform to the RESTful API standards.